# Am I required to setup a usermapping for a clientcertificate in order to have client certificate authentication to work as expected (in IIS)?

Tags: authentication, iis, client-certificates

Linked to [my question about client certificate authentication done the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407666/how-do-i-implement-client-certificate-authentication-the-right-way) I was wondering whether I have to take the step to link a certificate to a user (active directory or local user) in order to have clientcertificate authentication to work as expected?

And is it necessary to disable all other authentication schemes (anonymous, windows) for clientcerticate authentication to happen?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](http://forums.iis.net/t/1169534.aspx/1) on the IIS forum:

> This is what I would like to achieve:
>
> 1. A SSL-certificate for the URL itself (https://example.company.com). To my understanding this certificate does not have any connection whatsoever to client certificates.
> 2. Client certificates issued from my local CA and shared to trusted clients.
> 3. Some way of specifying which client certificates are allowed to connect to a specific IIS web site.
>
> 3 seems... complicated, to say the least. If I just set everything up and connect with a client certificate I have issued it works. The CA and the web server are on the same domain (if that matters), and I have added the root certificate from the CA to the trusted CAs on the web server. **However, at this stage I have not told the web server which client certificates to accept, so my first guess was that it accepts all client certificates [chained to] any CA it trusts.**

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325829/certificate-trust-lists-and-iis7), which links to [this site](http://viisual.net/configuration/IIS7-CTLs.htm), which is dead.

It comes down to creating a "Certificate Trust List", or to mapping certificates to user accounts.

You can however implement a custom certificate validator in your service, how to do so is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx).